# JavaScript Closure - trying to understand following code

Tags: javascript, closures

Coming from Java background trying to make sense out of the following code.

From: 
https://medium.freecodecamp.com/lets-learn-javascript-closures-66feb44f6a44#.cbk6c4e9g

For function **bar(c)**, which line passes argument **c** into **bar(c)** as I don't see it here.

Thanks.

```
var x = 10;
function foo(a) {
  var b = 20;

  function bar(c) {
    var d = 30;
    return boop(x + a + b + c + d);
  }

  function boop(e) {
    return e * -1;
  }

  return bar;
}

var moar = foo(5); // Closure  
/* 
  The function below executes the function bar which was returned 
  when we executed the function foo in the line above. The function bar 
  invokes boop, at which point bar gets suspended and boop gets push 
  onto the top of the call stack (see the screenshot below)
*/
moar(15);
```

Comment: if i understand correctly, function `foo` is returning `bar`. this effectively means any call to `foo` results in a call to `bar`. so the line `var moar = foo(5)` is calling `bar(5)`

Comment: @haxxxton OK that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Half right, `foo(5)` does indeed return the function `bar` within a closure where a is 5, but it does not call `bar`. The line below calls `bar`, which was assigned to variable moar, with parameter 15. Just like the comment says.

Comment: This also spooked me as a Java programmer, takes some getting used to

Comment: You get the same effect if you replace the last two lines with `foo(5)(15)`. `foo(5)` returns function bar within the closure, and then you call that function with `(5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your first statement of function call var moar = foo(5) is executed
 moar variable will be function bar(c){var d=30;return boop(x+a+b+c+d);

check the snippet for understanding

```js
var x = 10;
function foo(a) {
  var b = 20;

  function bar(c) {
    var d = 30;
    return boop(x + a + b + c + d);
  }
  return bar;
}

var moor=foo(10);
console.log(moor);
```

2.After this statement moar(15),your are actually passing 15 to the bar method

It will execute bar method with c as 15. Now this function would return boop(80) which would just be -80

```js
var x = 10;
function foo(a) {
  var b = 20;

  function bar(c) {
    var d = 30;
    return boop(x + a + b + c + d);
  }

  function boop(e) {
    return e * -1;
  }

  return bar;
}

var moar = foo(5)
console.log(moar(15));
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

`moar(15)` passes `15` into `bar` which gets copied into parameter `c`.

The `// Closure` comment is misleading because it is more useful to think of the closure being configured at the point of *declaration* of a function.

The reality is that the pointer to the outer lexical environment is configured when a function object is instantiated, and then this pointer is then copied to the execution context associated with any invocations of said function object.